# Order column by full name

Tags: mysql, sql, sequelize.js

I have a problem order by column name(String) when i have more than one word, like " Kafka Streams" and "Kafka Connectors". The order should be "Kafka Connectors", "Kafka Streams" but it order "Kafka Streams" ,"Kafka Connectors". The first word is ok, but second not. How can i resolve this?

I tried use substring and charindex, but the last one dont work in sequelize RAW queries.

```
sequelize.query(
            'SELECT  `technology`.`business_unit_id`, `technology`.`unit_reference_data_technology_id`' +
            'FROM `unit_reference_data_technology` AS `technology`' +
            'WHERE (`technology`.`description` LIKE (:name) ') ' +
            'ORDER BY `technology`.`description` ASC, LIMIT ' + limit + ' OFFSET ' + offset + '', { model: Models.unit_reference_data_technology, mapToModel: true, replacements: { business_unit_id, name: '%' + text + '%', limit: 10,}, type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJqih.png)

I m using MySQL and a Sequelize (nodeJS).
Can anyone help me? My solution is ORDER BY first word ASC, second word ASC ( If the string have always 2 words)

Comment: `CHARINDEX` is a SQL Server function.  What database are you actually using?

Comment: Also please include a larger sample data set.

Comment: could you provide data sample ? like a couple of rows of your result with all data filled in

Comment: Upper case letters come before lower case, so if you have `"Kaf seed"` and `"kaf col"`, then `"Kaf seed"` comes first, and your data is sorting properly. Look at any ASCII table and check the numeric values of `K` and `k`.

Comment: See my example image please, all words start with uppercase letters and S como first then C in ASC order

Comment: No, your example says *it order "Kaf seed", "kaf cot"*, with *Kaf seed* using an uppercase *K*.. Read your own post. Then read the other comments that have asked you for a better set of sample data. Even the data in your image will sort properly just using ASC. Post a CREATE TABLE with INSERT statements that will create a test sample, and the exact SQL you're using (without any other code) that does not work for you.

Comment: Ok, ty and sorry. What i want is if the first word of the string are the same, then order by the second. I go read about ASCII, ty